# Override thymeleaf templateEngine configuration stops working in Spring Boot 2.1.8

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, configuration, thymeleaf

I have a running Spring Boot 2.0.1 application. After upgrading to Spring Boot 2.1.8, I get the following error during startup:

`The bean 'templateEngine', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [my/package/ThymeleafConfig.class] and overriding is disabled.`

I don't use AutoConfiguration, so I cannot understand why the ThymeleafAutoConfiguration class kicks in.

Also I don't want the autoconfigured templateEngine to be used, but my own definition of templateEngine. So enabling bean-overriding is not an option here. (Remember: It wants to override my correctly registered bean with the default version, which is not what I want)

Here is my bean definition (overriding templateEngine):

```
public class MyThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        ...
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ISpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

I know that Spring Boot has altered something in the bean registration process, according to the 2.1. release notes:

> Bean overriding has been disabled by default to prevent a bean being accidentally overridden. If you are relying on overriding, you will need to set spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding to true.

But I don't think this applies here. In fact I DON'T want my bean to be overridden. If I set the above parameter, the app comes up, but uses the default thymeleaf templateEngine.

And finally: The templateEngine bean in ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration has a @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation. So if a bean is already there, imho it just should leave it and not try to override.

I think, I am missing something vital here. Any thoughts will be welcome. Thanks in advance.
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Switching again back to my former running application and do deep debugging there shed some light in this matter.

What I found: I never used my own templateEngine bean that I defined in the config (see code in question). Both versions of the app have at runtime: a viewResolver that contains a default templateEngine (from the ThymeleafAutoConfiguration) that contains two templateResolvers (a default one and my own, defined in my config). Removing the templateEngine bean definition in my config made the app start up, this is the solution to the problem. So the disabled overriding in Spring Boot >2.1.0 indeed led to the described behaviour, because my (useless) bean definition was not overridden automatically.

Still there are some questions left:
- Obviously my app runs fine with the default templateEngine. But what if I really need to override it? right now I don't have the possibility, because defining my own will fail in starting up and if I allow overriding, the default one is used. Anyone having an explanation to this, feel free to add it in a comment.
- What is the use of the @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation in the ThymeleafAutoConfiguration when it's obviously ignored, resulting in the error described in the question. Here too, I'm willing and eager to learn. so please share your thoughts in the comments.

Thanks, Patrick